# Type "left double quotes" using ANY US compatible keyboard layout

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

Is it possible to type accented characters as well as quotes like “ (please note this is not normal double quotes. its the 'left double quotes')

I was wondering if there is ' and ` then there should be a way to type " and “ as well

Comment: If you change the font name it will change

Comment: Actually ' and ` are not ‘ and ’ ;)

Comment: those are called [smart quotes](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Change-curly-quotes-to-straight-quotes-and-vice-versa-017963a0-bc5f-486b-9c9d-0ec511a8fb8f)

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to bypass any keyboard layout or language and make any characters available in Windows. It does require a numpad though. For instance, in relation to your question, hold down ALT+0147 (“) and ALT+0148 (”). There are several sites that can provide a full list of symbols and how to create them. Here's an example:

https://usefulshortcuts.com/alt-codes/punctuation-alt-codes.php